# How to `file_get_contents()` multiple files?

Tags: php, json, symfony

I have a directory with more than 10K json files and i need to parse them all. The parse function works very well for 1 file but i don't see how to loop every file in the directory.

Contrôler:

```
 public function parseFile()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->getRepository('NcstoxBundle:JsonTextMining');

    foreach (glob('*.json') as $file) {

        set_include_path('/home/landreau/workspace/NCSTOX/web/assets/json/sample-json');
        $json = file_get_contents($file, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
        $array = json_decode($json, true);
        var_dump($json);
        print_r($array);


        foreach ($array as $item) {
            $jsonTextMining = new JsonTextMining();
            $jsonTextMining->setSolrId($item['id']);
            $jsonTextMining->setOriginalPaper($item['Original_paper']);
            $jsonTextMining->setAnnotatedFile($item['Annotated_file']);
            $jsonTextMining->setTitle($item['Title']);
            foreach ($item['Molecule'] as $mol) {
                $jsonTextMining->setMoleculeName($mol['Main name']);
            }
            $jsonTextMining->setSynonymName($item['Molecule'][0]['Synonyms']);
            $jsonTextMining->setKeyword($item['ToxKeywords']);
            $jsonTextMining->setImportantSentence($item['Important_sentences'][0]);


            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($jsonTextMining);
        }
    }
    $em->flush();


    return new Response('Saved new document with id ');
}
```

I tried to `glob()` function but the loop ends without saving anything.

Did someone know a better syntax to loop over all files in directory and then `file_get_contents()` them ?

Comment: Use the Filesystem symfony component to read all files within that directory, and then get the content for each file.

Comment: Thanks i just looked at the documentation about it and it could be a good solution and i learned something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use `DirectoryIterator` for looping over files in a directory, as it gives you built-in methods for all the various parsing that you're likely to do. Just instantiate it with the directory name and then iterate over it:

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator('/path/to/files') as $file) {
    if ($file->getExtension() === 'json') {
        $array = json_decode(file_get_contents($file->getPathname()), true);
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution seems to be a good one but now i get an error `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` for my other loop that worked fine just before

Comment: it's the ` foreach ($array as $item) {`

Comment: Then `$array` isn't an array, which means either the `json_decode()` is failing or the JSON file doesn't contain an array.

Comment: i think this is probably one (or more) json file that is responsible because using your solution i could fill the database with about 300 files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [The Finder Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html#usage)

Comment: Yes and it supports glob. Adding a code example would help to get more upvotes. ;)

Comment: I'm not sure that this is an answer -- looks more like a link-only software recommendation that is probably better placed as a comment under the question.